# Vim: Navigate through Latex-document structure

Tags: vim, latex

Is there any vim-tool providing an efficient navigation through a Latex-document structure. It would be very useful to have something like a NERDTree panel representing the sections/subsection structure of the latex-document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tagbar` plugin can show an outline of my latex file. (section, subsections etc.)

http://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar

right side is the tagbar window, I have enlarged it a little:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, always something. The problem is, the tags are sorted by their level, that is, first go all the chapters, then all the sections, then all the subsections and so on. It's not very convenient as long as it's not a tree structure: a chapter, a list of all of its sections, for each section a list of all subsections, only then another chapter... Isn't there a solution which would work this way?

Answer (score 8):

Expanding mnosefishs answer (thanks by the way, it was you who made me discover VOoM):

VOoM seems indeed to be the best choice. It comes with latex support: Install it and type 
:Voom latex
and it will show you a sidebar with a foldable structure outline allowing you to navigate in your tex file.

[image]

As mentioned by kamilk, tagbars (in my view decisive) problem is the fact that it groups parts to parts, sections to sections instead of nesting them.
VOoM works with folds instead of tags, so it's better suited for a structure outline, use tabbar if you want an overview by syntax elements.

Quoting from tabbar man:
Sort has been disabled for LaTeX so that the sections appear in their correct
order. They unfortunately can't be shown nested with their correct scopes
since as already mentioned the regular expression approach doesn't support
that.

Answer (score 5):

You might try using the vim plugin [VOoM](https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script.php?script_id=2657), which might be able to hyperlink the sections.

From the Plugin Description:

> VOoM (Vim Outliner of Markups) is a plugin for Vim that emulates a two-pane text outliner.
>
> VOoM can currently handle >20 markup formats that have headlines and support an outline structure, including popular lightweight markup languages such as reST, Markdown, Pandoc, AsciiDoc, Org-mode, Wiki, LaTeX, etc. (Headlines are also called headings, headers, section headers, titles.)

Answer (score 5):

The [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) plugin provides the command `VimtexTocOpen` which opens an outline. This might be more useful when browsing large LaTeX documents, because it scans the whole project, i.e. it also looks into `includes` or `inputs` and shows them correctly.

Comment: `\lt` will open the table of contents.

Answer (score 2):

VimTex is a comprehensive latex-plugin for vim and neovim. For navigation, use `:VimtexTocToggle`. An interactive table of contents that includes latex-sections, labels and references will be shown in a new window (see picture). You can simple select the part place you want to go and press enter. You will jump to the corresponding place in the document.

[VimTex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) also provides many other useful features. Including navigating between latex and pdf file. Use `<leader>lv` to jump to the place in pdf corresponding to current cursor position in latex file. Control-leftclick on pdf-file will reposition the cursor on correponding position in the latex file.

VimTex Toc(table of contents) Toggle:
[image: [VimTex Toc(table of contents) Toggle]]